# 2d to Isometric formula

Tags: actionscript-3, 2d, isometric, cartesian

tileWidth is 64 and tileHeight is 32.

This is my map array:

```
var map:Array=
    [
        [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [2,3,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2],
        [2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2],
        [2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2],
        [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
    ];
```

Here is how theyre being placed:

```
//place tiles
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < map.length; i++)
        {
            for (var j:Number = 0; j < map[i].length; j++)
            {
                placeTile(map[i][j],i,j);
            }
        }

//place the tile based on coordinates
    private function placeTile(id:uint,i:uint,j:uint)
    {
        var pos:Point=new Point();
        pos.x = i;
        pos.y = j;
        pos = twoDToIso(pos);

        tile = new MovieClip(atlas.getTextures(getTile(id)),20);
        tile.x = pos.x ;
        //tile.y = pos.y + (map.length/2)*tileHeight - tileHeight*4 ;//used to center
        tile.y = pos.y;
        tile.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, mapDown);
        mapContainer.addChild(tile);
    }
```

This is the function used to plot out the 2d points to isometric:

```
//CONVERT POINT TO ISOMETRIC
    private function twoDToIso(pt:Point):Point
    {
        trace(" ");
        trace("twoDtoIso:");
        trace("2d: " + pt);
        var tempPt:Point = new Point(0,0);

        tempPt.x = (pt.x * tileWidth / 2) + (pt.y * tileWidth / 2);
        tempPt.y =  (pt.y * tileHeight / 2) - (pt.x * tileHeight / 2);


        trace("iso: " + tempPt);
        return (tempPt);
    }
```

What formula can I use to revert the coordinates I receive when clicking a tile, back to 2d / access to the map array?

Comment: Correct your tags. "iso" has nothing to do with it. "cartesian" is kind of the opposite of "isometric". You forgot a (*any*) language tag. Finally, did you attempt anything?

Comment: I've attempted a lot. Language isn't necessary as it would just be a formula. If I can retrieve the isometric coordinates from array indexes then I should be able to revert the coordinates I get by clicking to access the array.

tempPt.x=Math.floor(pt.x/tileHeight);
tempPt.y=Math.floor(pt.y/tileHeight);

This seems to only work if the screen itself was a grid, not for the tiles being placed isometrically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation from screen coordinates back to isometric is the inverse of your own `twoDToIso`: for every 2 pixels across the x axis, you subtract 1 from the y axis, so for the reverse you do the same for pixels across the *y* axis. (Hope that's as clear as I think it is.)

However, the signs of the calculations depend on how your map is set up: with the x axis going diagonally *up* to the right, or *down* to the right (and, possibly, the same for y). I did my testing with a diagonal up-map, with y counting up to the lower right:

```
             +x
          ..
       2,0   ..
   1,0   2,1    ..
0,0   1,1   2,2    ..
   0,1   1,2   ..
      0,2   ..
         ..+y
```

If your map is drawn differently, swap the signs for the x,y calculations (and possibly for the constant 32 as well).

The conversion from mouse coordinates `mx,my` to isometric coordinates `tilex,tiley` is the following:

```
int tilex = mx - 2*my + 32;
int tiley = mx + 2*my - 32;

tilex /= 64;
tiley /= 64;

drawcursor (tilex, tiley);
```

and is pixel-perfect for tiles of 128x64:

[image: isometric cursor movement]

Moving the mouse cursor only one pixel lower will select the blank space to the right and below the blue selected tile.

There is a small oddity here: the black space in the lower half of my image is "negative x", and when entering that, the cursor needs a further adjustment of +1 for the isometric x position. This is because in C<sup>[*]</sup> by default an integer is rounded "towards zero". Using floats and `floor` made it work; but in general, you should strive to use integers for frequent calculations such as these. (Also, I don't think that a negative x or y position would be valid in regular tile maps.)

<sup>[*]</sup> I wrote my test program with C and SDL.

If you want to be able to select individual *pixels* inside each tile (for instance, if you want to select a certain quarter of a tile), you can use the fractional part of `tilex` and `tiley`:

```
innerx = tilex & 63;
innery = tiley & 63;
```

before doing the division by 64.

Comment: It makes sense looking at it, but i really can't get this thing to work, it's frustrating me. I'm using feathers with starling / flash. For some reason I can't place objects with negative values in the scrollContainer so I give each y value an increase of 512 (this centers the 40 tile long map on the screen). I'm assuming that is what is giving me wonky values. But I adjust the 512 before calculating.


[0,0,0]
[0,1,0]
[0,0,1]

This will draw the 1 tiles down and to the right the way my map is being drawn.

Comment: Well .. adjusting your y position by 512 *should* not make a difference (subtract 512 from the mouse y position before doing my calculation). The problem may lie, as I already noted, in the orientation of your map. I moved mine around to draw back-to-front.

Comment: Alright thanks for the detailed response. I'll give it another by redoing it all and starting fresh, hopefully it works out.